# Можно ли с помощью PHP узнать откуда подключается файл?

Tags: php

На стороннем сайте будет подключаться js файл. В нем будет исполняться JS код. Можно ли узнать адрес сайта, откуда идет запрос?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Шлите AJAX'ом из JS запросы к себе на сервер с указанием URL.

Comment: аяксом не получится кроссдоменный запрос. Можно подгружать контент типа картинки, а в адресе картинки передавать нужные данные.

Comment: Если скрипт подключен со стороннего сайта, то его запросы к этом сайту не являются кроссдоменными.

Answer (score 1):

всмысле вы будете предоставлять свой JS файл разным сайтам? Если так - то ссылка на JS файл делайте не на прямую а через php скрипт, а внем уже можно и узнать откуда запрос пришел

Comment: ... ну или настроить лог на сервере